# Having issues with flickering output to TV from Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, video, thinkpad

I cannot tell why this is happening. I cannot get a pattern as to when it happens. Sometimes, I watch entire Hulu content without any interruptions. Other times, it happens 2-3 times in a span of 3 minutes. Then it stops for 10-15 minutes.

- Lenovo T410s
- Integrated graphics: Intel HD Graphics (Driver=8.15.10.2253, Video BIOS=2026.1)
- TV is a Zenith (does not happen with other laptop so doubt it's TV)
- TV connected to laptop using HDMI-to-DVI cable (previously was connected directly via DVI but I bought a new cable and it's still happening)

Anyone could help me troubleshoot this? I'd greatly appreciate it. If you need more information, I'll be glad to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem with a Lenovo too. This is what I did to fix the issue.

Open the Properties window of your video adapter. Usually there's an icon for your graphics display properties on the lower right corner. Once you open the properties window, there are options for multimedia, 3d, etc. Set them from "low" to "quality". Hope this works... :)

Comment: +1 for giving me hope heh. I only see the "3D" tab. There is a scaler that goes from "Performance" to "Quality" with another notch in the middle. Should I set that to "Quality"? I do not see the "Multimedia" one.

Comment: set it to quality... :D